# jquery or not / Cross Browser Compatible iframe resize (IE, Chrome, Safari, Firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-browser

Here is my issue. I have been looking hard for a cross browser iframe resize code to use and i just cant find one. All i have seen has issues in one browser over another. Here is what i am doing. I am loading an iframe into the page in an jquery tools overlay. This iframe will load contents of a page (on the same domain so dont need to worry about cross domain). When a user clicks an action on that form the iframe will again need to resize (i have it working for when the iframe increases but not when the iframe decreases).

I have a js file that is included in the iframe which has this function

```
$(window).load(function(){
    parent.adjust_iframe();
});
```

That function then calls the parent pages function like so:

```
function adjust_iframe() {

    //i have tried both body and html and both dont work in IE
    var h = $("#overlayFrame").contents().find("body").height();
    if(h==0)
    h="500";
    else
    h=h+3;

    $("#overlayFrame").css({'height': h});
    window.scrollTo(0,0);

}
```

The above code works fine in Chrome and firefox but not in IE.

Any help here? I really need a cross browser compatible light weight solution that doesnt involve some heavy jquery plugin that isnt supported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var bodyHeight = $('body').height();
    parent.adjust_iframe( bodyHeight );
});
```

and

```
function adjust_iframe(newHeight) {

    //i have tried both body and html and both dont work in IE
    if(newHeight == 0) {
       newHeight = 500;
    } else {
       newHeight += 3;
    }

    $("#overlayFrame").css({'height': newHeight});
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Because the problem is probably that the page cannot access the iframes contents..

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions:

When you are setting the CSS height, explicitly tell it pixels.

```
$("#overlayFrame").css({'height': h + 'px'});
```

When your iframe code is calling parent.adjust_iframe, send the current width/height.

```
parent.adjust_iframe($('body').height());
```

BONUS suggestion: Do a little investigation and tell us what version of IE and why it doesn't work. Put some alerts in there and find out if the height is getting derived etc.

Comment: i did alerts and in IE8 i get a alert saying height is 150. That is the original size of the iframe before it adjusted

Answer (score -1):

I've searched my archived files and found script which sets new size of iframe window. It was working on IE6, FF,...

```
/**
 * Parent
 */
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframe" ...>

<script type="text/javascript">
var iframeids=["myframe"];
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("load", resizeCaller, false);
}else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent("onload", resizeCaller);
} else {
  window.onload=resizeCaller;
}
var iframehide="yes";
var getFFVersion=navigator.userAgent.substring(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox")).split("/")[1];
var FFextraHeight=parseFloat(getFFVersion)>=0.1? 20 : 0;
function resizeCaller() {
  var dyniframe=new Array();
  for (i=0; i<iframeids.length; i++){
    if (document.getElementById)
      resizeIframe(iframeids[i]);
    if ((document.all || document.getElementById) && iframehide=="no"){
      var tempobj=document.all? document.all[iframeids[i]] : document.getElementById(iframeids[i]);
      tempobj.style.display="";
    }
  }
};

function resizeIframe(frameid){
  var currentfr=document.getElementById(frameid);
  if (currentfr && !window.opera){
    currentfr.style.display="";
    if (currentfr.contentDocument && currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight)
      currentfr.height = currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight+FFextraHeight; 
    else if (currentfr.Document && currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight)
      currentfr.height = currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight;
    if (currentfr.addEventListener)
      currentfr.addEventListener("load", readjustIframe, false);
    else if (currentfr.attachEvent){
      currentfr.detachEvent("onload", readjustIframe);
      currentfr.attachEvent("onload", readjustIframe);
    }
  }
};
function readjustIframe(loadevt) {
  var crossevt=(window.event)? event : loadevt;
  var iframeroot=(crossevt.currentTarget)? crossevt.currentTarget : crossevt.srcElement;
  if (iframeroot)resizeIframe(iframeroot.id);
};

function loadintoIframe(iframeid, url){
  if (document.getElementById)document.getElementById(iframeid).src=url;
};
</script>

/**
 * child iFrame html
 */
<body onResize="resizeIE()">
```